# How do I wrap adjacent elements of the same class using Javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

Everywhere I looked, it seemed that this problem has only been solved using jQuery, which I'm trying to remove completely from my project.
Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="codeblock"></div>
<div class="codeblock"></div>
<div class="codeblock"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="codeblock"></div>
<div class="codeblock"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="codeblock"></div>
```

desired result:

```
<div class="contentBox">
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="contentBox">
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
</div>
<p></p>
<div class="contentBox">
   <div class="codeblock"></div>
</div>
```

And here's how this can be done using jQuery, thanks to the many answers I've found on the topic

```
const e = '.codeblock';
$(e).not(e + '+' + e).each(function () {
$(this).nextUntil(':not(' + e + ')').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="contentBox" />');
});
```

Is there a way to replicate this same functionality using vanilla Javascript? I've tried using Element.nextElementSibling and checking if the class matches, but this approach wasn't very elegant and resulted in much more code than the jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest version I could come up with:

```
let firstDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.codeblock:first-child, :not(.codeblock) + .codeblock');

firstDivs.forEach(function(div) {
  let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.className = 'wrapper';
  div.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, div);
  while(div.nextElementSibling && div.nextElementSibling.className == 'codeblock') {
    wrapper.appendChild(div.nextElementSibling);
  }
  wrapper.insertBefore(div, wrapper.firstChild);
});
```

First, select the first `.codeblock` element out of each "group" - by selecting the element with that class that is the first child of its parent, and all those that do not have a `.codeblock` element before them.

For each of those elements, insert a new wrapper div before that element, then loop through the following element siblings, as long as they have that same class - and append those to the wrapper. And then afterwards, insert the first item to the beginning of the group. (If we did it before, the following elements would stop being siblings at this point.)

Comment: All of the answers are great, but this one was definitely the easiest to understand and read. I noticed that in your querySelectorAll you're selecting the first element using .codeblock:first-child, but I'm curious what the purpose and function of the second selector is.

Comment: The `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) - `A + B` selects the element `B`, if it is the next sibling directly following `A`. So I am using `:not(.codeblock) + .codeblock` to select all `.codeblock` elements, that do _not_ have another `.codeblock` element in front of them, but something else. And because the very first `.codeblock` does not have something else in front of it either, we select that with the first part, `.codeblock:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
// Find all elements that match the class
document.querySelectorAll(`.${e}`).forEach(
    // For each elemnt
    elem => {
        // If it's not the first of the group, skip it
        if (elem.previousElementSibling!==null && elem.previousElementSibling.classList.contains(e)){
            return;
        }

        // Find all adjacent elements with the same class
        let o = [elem];
        while (o[o.length - 1].nextElementSibling.classList.contains(e)) {
             o.push(o[o.length - 1].nextElementSibling);
        }

        // Create a new wrapper element and give it a proper class
        let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
        wrapper.classList.add('contentBox');

        // Insert the new wrapper immediatly before the group
        elem.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', wrapper);

        // Move the contents of the group to inside the wrapper element
        wrapper.replaceChildren(...o);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more code, but you can loop through all `div` and `p`, check every element and when matched append it to a new or existing `div.codeBlock`.

```js
const isTargeted = el => el.classList.contains(`codeblock`);
const createWrap = (beforeEl) => beforeEl.insertAdjacentElement(`beforebegin`, 
  Object.assign(document.createElement(`div`), {className: `contentBox`}));
const divsAndPs = document.querySelectorAll(`div, p`);
divsAndPs.forEach(
  (elem, i, self) => {
    if (!i || isTargeted(elem)) {
      const wrap = i && self[i-1].closest(`.contentBox`) || 
        createWrap(elem);
      wrap.appendChild(elem);
    } 
  }
);
```

```css
.contentBox {
  color: green;
}

.contentBox .codeblock {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.contentBox:before {
  content: 'I am the great contentBox, here are my codeblocks:';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
```

This can be a helper function (see also this [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-kua1kc?file=script.js)):

```js
const wrapIt = () => wrapAll(
  document.querySelectorAll(`.codeblock, .codeblock + :not(.codeblock)`),
  `codeblock`,
  Object.assign(document.createElement(`div`), {className: `contentBox`}) );
setTimeout( wrapIt, 1000 );

function wrapAll(elems2Wrap, groupByClass, wrapperElement) {
  const wrap = elem =>
    elem.classList?.contains(groupByClass) && (elem
      .previousElementSibling?.closest(`.${wrapperElement.className}`) ||
      elem.insertAdjacentElement(`beforebegin`, wrapperElement.cloneNode())
    ).appendChild(elem);
  elems2Wrap.forEach(wrap);
}
```

```css
.contentBox {
  color: green;
}

.contentBox .codeblock {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.contentBox:before {
  content: 'Wrapped!';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="codeblock otherClass">x</div>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<p>Just a paragraph</p>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
<div class="codeblock otherClass">x</div>
<p>Just a paragraph</p>
<div class="codeblock">x</div>
```